# reading config file from different folder java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a config file based on the code here:

http://www.opencodez.com/java/read-config-file-in-java.htm

So I found that if the config.cfg is in same directory as of where I am running the code, then everything is fine but if the config is at different directory

```
example: /path/to/config.cfg
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
at packagename.conf.Config.<init>(Config.java:14)
at packagename.conf.Config.main(Config.java:30)
```

My guess is it is not able to find the file.
But how do I modify the above code to read config file from a different folder?
Thanks

Edit: Code from the link:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config 
{
   Properties configFile;
   public Config()
   {
    configFile = new java.util.Properties();
    try {           
      configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
      getResourceAsStream("myapp/config.cfg"));         
    }catch(Exception eta){
        eta.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   public String getProperty(String key)
   {
    String value = this.configFile.getProperty(key);        
    return value;
   }
}
```

Comment: The actual code you use for opening the file would be very helpful here

Comment: @AlexanderWeinert: HI.. its the same code from the link. I just copy pasted :)

Comment: It will definitely throw `FileNotFoundException`. To get rid of this either gave it a `absolute path` or `specific relative path`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you posted expects the configuration-file to be on the classpath (that is, in the same sorts of places that Java looks for your `.class` files). So, you can either include the directory containing the configuration-file in the classpath:

```
java   -classpath .:/path/to   packagename.conf.Config
```

Or else you can modify the code to expect the configuration-file to be a regular filesystem file:

```
final InputStream cfg = new FileInputStream("/path/to/config.cfg");
try
    { configFile.load(cfg); }
finally
    { cfg.close(); }
```